# Loading Actual Class Values and File Names

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I have trained a basic image classifier and am stuck at quite a basic issue when trying to assess the results.

I am struggling to load the actual values of my validation data and corresponding file names for each image, so they can be compared to the `model.predict` values.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jan  3 21:21:02 2021

@author: Sam
"""

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_examples = 425
test_examples = 245
validation_examples = 245
img_height = img_width = 224
batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model = keras.models.load_model('isic_model4/')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1.0/255,
    rotation_range = 15,
    zoom_range = (0.95, 0.95),
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    data_format = "channels_last",
    dtype = tf.float32,
    )

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255, dtype=tf.float32)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255, dtype=tf.float32)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "ClassifierData/Training/",
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "binary",
    shuffle = False,
    seed = 123,
    )

validation_gen = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "ClassifierData/Validation/",
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "binary",
    shuffle = False,
    seed = 123,
    )
    
test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "ClassifierData/Test/",
    target_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "binary",
    shuffle = False,
    seed = 123,
    )

METRICS = [
    keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name="accuracy"),
    keras.metrics.Precision(name="precision"),
    keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall"),
    keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
    ]

valpred1 = model.predict_classes(validation_gen)
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a Jupyter Notebook? Could you add in the directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the validation_gen file names and labels with

```
filenames=validation_gen.filenames
labels=validation_gen.labels
```

If you set shuffle=False in the validation_gen.flow_from_directory the generator will provide the files to model.predict in the order they are in in filenames. You can use the code below to generate the predictions and print the results showing the filenames

```
file_names=valididation_gen.filenames
labels=valididation_gen.labels
preds=model.predict(valididation_gen)
print('{0:^3s}{1:^15s}{2:^11s}{3:^16s}{4:^7s}'.format ('i', 'File Name', 'True Class', 'Predicted Class','Error' ))
for i in range(len(preds)):
    p=np.argmax(preds[i])
    if p==labels[i]:
        error='No'
    else:
        error='Yes'
    print ('{0:^3s}{1:^15s}{2:^11s}{3:^16s}{4:^7s}'.format ( str(i), file_names[i], str(labels[i]), str(p), error ))
```

you will get a printed output that is similar to this but with your own filenames

```
 i    File Name   True Class Predicted Class  Error 
 0 class0\001.jpg      0            0          No   
 1 class0\002.jpg      0            0          No   
 2 class0\003.jpg      0            0          No   
 3 class0\004.jpg      0            0          No   
 4 class0\005.jpg      0            0          No   
 5 class0\006.jpg      0            0          No   
 6 class0\007.jpg      0            0          No   
 7 class0\008.jpg      0            0          No   
 8 class0\009.jpg      0            0          No   
 9 class0\010.jpg      0            0          No   
10 class1\011.jpg      1            1          No   
11 class1\012.jpg      1            1          No
```